# Como alterar a função do meu botão de salvar, para alterar

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

Eu tenho alguns dados cadastrados no banco, e queria saber como faço pra mudar a função de inserir no banco para alterar os dados, utilizando um `Button`, eu consigo puxar os dados e joga-los nos `TextBoxs` através do `DataGrid`, porém queria alterar e salvar as alterações

Aqui eu Utilizo meu botão `btnSalvar` para inserir no banco

```
 private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // campos vazios
        if (txtNome.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("O nome do produto está vazio, por favor digite algo");
        }
        else if (txtPreco.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            if (txtPreco.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("O Preço do produto está vazio, por favor digite algo");
            }
            else
            {

            }
            //fim dps campos vazios
        }            
        //eniando para o banco
        else
        {
            try
            {
                conectar.Open();
                //Convertendo

                Converter = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPreco.Text);

                //MessageBox.Show("Conectado");

                MySqlCommand Inserir = new MySqlCommand();
                Inserir.Connection = conectar;
                Inserir.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Produto (Nome, Descricao, Preco, `status`) VALUES (@peca, @nome, @quantidade, @dataentrada)";

                Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peca", txtNome.Text);
                Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtDescricao.Text);
                Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", txtPreco.Text);
                Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataentrada", ckbAtiv.Checked);

                Inserir.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conectar.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Cadastro Realizado!", "Concluido",
                  MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                  MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                selecionarCategoria();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falha na conexao!", "falha",
                  MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                  MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
```

E aqui eu eu consigo jogar os valores do `DataGrid` para os `TextBoxs`

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        txtNome.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtDescricao.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtPreco.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: @CypherPotato editei a pergunta para tentar deixar mais clara

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma condição especificando se já foi salvo o objeto, e se for verdadeiro, indica que o botão irá realizar uma alteração.

```
bool informacoesSalvas = false;

private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(informacoesSalvas)
    {
         // código para salvar o objeto
         ...
         informacoesSalvas = true;
    } else {
         // código para inserir no objeto
    }
}
```

Para evitar a repetição de código, aplique as condicionais fora da execução do bloco dos comandos do banco de dados, desta forma:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNome.Text)) {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("O nome do produto está vazio, por favor digite algo");
    return; // sai do método
}
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPreco.Text)) {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("O Preço do produto está vazio, por favor digite algo");
    return;
}

if(informacoesSalvas)
{
    // código para salvar o objeto
   ...
    informacoesSalvas = true;
} else {
    // código para inserir no objeto
}
```

Assim é como ficaria o seu código.

Comment: como seria o código do comentário `// Código para Salvar o objeto` tipo, eu tenho o de inserir, seria a mesma coisa ?

Comment: @PietroNunciaroni praticamente o seu código inteiro dentro do `Try...Catch`. Você precisa fazer duas implementações para o banco de dados: o que salva o objeto, e o que atualiza o objeto. Ali no código você performa estas implementações.

Comment: ele apresentou um outro erro, editei a pergunta, junto com o codigo novo que você aconselhou

Comment: @PietroNunciaroni, isso não segue as normas do Stack Overflow. Você deve considerar se a minha resposta respondeu a pergunta para a sua questão. Se aconteceu um novo erro, diferente do que foi perguntado, deve ser criada uma nova pergunta, indicando esse novo erro. Se você quiser, poderá colocar um link para essa questão, mostrando o que já foi feito antes. Vou reverter suas edições e espero que você crie uma nova pergunta, para que receba uma nova resolução.

Comment: obrigado, desculpa me confundi um pouco, eu criei uma nova pergunta e ja me ajudaram la, desculpe o transtorno

Comment: a, uma pergunta antes, o que vai realmente dentro de cada comentário no código ?

Comment: @PietroNunciaroni seria o indicado para colocar o conteúdo que está dentro do seu bloco `try...catch`. O primeiro seria um, com implementação em SQL para **salvar o arquivo**, e o de baixo, seria o indicado para **atualizar o arquivo**.

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi muito bem ainda essa questão, não sei como ele poderia ficar, também não consigo achar nenhum exemplo disso

Comment: No seu próprio código tem o exemplo disso. Está dentro do bloco `try...catch`.

Comment: Bom acabei fazendo de uma maneira diferente, acabou dando certo, porém ainda não altera no banco, ele da a mensagem **alterado com sucesso!** porém ainda não altera no banco segue o [Links](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/371435/como-alterar-um-dado-no-bd/371446?noredirect=1#comment739014_371446), se puder dar uma olhada e me ajudar agradeço