# Como Alterar um dado no BD

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

Estou tentando Alterar os dados cadastrados no Banco de dados, por exemplo, quando Clico no `DataGrid` ele puxa pra mim os dados para os `textBoxs`, mas eu queria poder salvar as alterações feitas, porém ele não altera, aparece a uma `MenssageBox` dizendo que o cadastro foi alterado, porem tanto no `DataGrid` quanto no BD não esta sendo atualizado

código que estou usando:

```
private void btnSalvar2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            

            MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=ProdPacote; Uid=root; pwd=1234;");
            conectar.Open();

            var transaction = conectar.BeginTransaction();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Produto SET Nome = @NOME, Descricao = @DESCRICAO, PRECO = @PRECO, STATUS = @STATUS WHERE ID_Produto = @ID", conectar);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", txtNome.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descricao", txtDescricao.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Preco", txtPreco.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", ativIndat);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lblID);                

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            transaction.Commit();
            conectar.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Produto alterado", "Concluido",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            selecionarCategoria();
            btnSalvar.Visible = true;
            btnSalvar2.Visible = false;

    }
```

**Note:** estou usando a Mysql como banco, segue uma foto do código

```
CREATE DATABASE ProdPacote;
USE ProdPacote;

CREATE TABLE Produto(
ID_Produto INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nome VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Descricao VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Preco DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`status` TINYINT NOT NULL);  

CREATE TABLE Pacote(
ID_Pacote INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nome VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
peca VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
Quantidade INT NOT NULL,
Data_entrada DATETIME NOT NULL);
#Data_saida DATE NOT NULL




CREATE TABLE Produto_Pacote(
ID_Produto_Pacote INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Data_Hora DATE NOT NULL,
FK_ID_Produto INT NOT NULL,
FK_ID_Pacote INT NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT Produto_Pacote
FOREIGN KEY (FK_ID_Produto)
REFERENCES Produto (ID_Produto),

CONSTRAINT Pacote_Produto
FOREIGN KEY(FK_ID_Pacote)
REFERENCES Pacote(ID_Pacote));
```

Comment: Pietro, tente colocar este código em SQL em código escrito aqui na publicação, por gentileza.

Comment: Seria importante clicar em [edit] e reduzir sua postagem a um [mcve] somente com o necessário para reproduzir o problema. Da forma como está depende de análise completa do seu código, o que não é adequado para o formato do site. Além disto, em situações normais. código não deve ser postado como imagem.

Comment: @CypherPotato, como faço para colocar o código em Mysql, meio que fica todo bagunçado se Utilizar as ``Code``

Comment: ou como faço pra te chamar no chat pra poder enviar, ou como faço pra mostrar ele

Comment: @PietroNunciaroni só colocar quatro espaços antes de cada linha do código, igual fez no do C#.

Comment: @CypherPotato, atualizei a pergunta, porém ainda não consigo fazer o `btnSalvar2` alterar os dados cadastrados

Comment: @CypherPotato, Exemplo: ele aparece a mensagem que foi alterado, porém ainda não altera no banco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No final da string  `"UPDATE Produto SET Nome = @NOME, Descricao = @DESCRICAO, PRECO = @PRECO, STATUS = @STATUS WHERE ID = @ID"` que é passa para o constructor `MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(...` está escrito assim `WHERE ID = @ID`.

O parâmetro `@ID` não foi definido em `command`. Para solucionar defina o parâmetro '@ID':

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Valor_do_ID);
```

onde `Valor_do_ID` você substitui pela fonte desse id.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91624/discussion-on-answer-by-augusto-vasques-como-alterar-um-dado-no-bd)